# Create your own header

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to create af header like chapters. The command should be `\Apendiks{}` and then it should do like if I had written `\chapters{The first Chapter}`.

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ 
    \normalfont\bf\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}
    \selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]
```

I still want to have the opportunity to use the `\chapter` command, so a solution like this: `\newcommand{\Appendiks}{\chapter}` will not be sufficient.

[image]

This is what I have managed to do so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\Appendiks}{\subsubsection}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bf\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]
\begin{document}
\Appendiks{The first Appendix}
\end{document}
```

But I don't think it is the best soulutons to define `\Appendiks` as `\subsubsection`.

Any better sugestions ??

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are asking for but it does sound like you might be looking for the already existing `\appendix` command.

Comment: Btw, Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Thansk for the warm welcome, but this what not, what I wanted. My code is:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}

\end{document}

Comment: @Simon: Your question is quite unclear. Please do as Andrew asked and perhaps provide a sketch/screenshot how the header should look like

Comment: How can I show the screenshot ? I can't see any bottom on this page to do that.

Comment: When you edit your question you can see little icons on top of the edit box, one of them is for including pictures.

Comment: So, to be sure, you want an `article` document to have `chapter`s? Why not using `report` or `book`, where they are predefined?

Comment: Let me try to explain again. I agree, It would be much easier, if I could could show you a screenshot, but I don't know how to upload it. For example, If you write:

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
\end{document}

Latex show you its standard header for sections. I want to write my own style of "sections", which command name should be "\Appendiks"

Comment: The way it should look like should be like this:
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ 
    \normalfont\bf\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}
    \selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]

Is that more clear ??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not se that bottom. No, I do not want to create chapters. It was an example of a text header already defined by latex. I want to create my own using an an article document.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a screenshot on how to upload a picture.

Comment: Sorry I'm so cumbersome. I'm new at this forum.

Comment: This is what I have managed to do so far:

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\Appendiks}{\subsubsection}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}%pbk
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bf\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]
\begin{document}
\Appendiks{The first Appendix}
\end{document} 

But I don't think it is the best soulutons to define \Appendiks as \subsubsection.

Any better sugestions ??

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a `\chapter` command that can be used interchangeably with the `\appendix` command.  This is certainly doable, though it's hard to see why, once you've used an appendix, you'd still want a normal chapter.  `book.cls` defines the `\chapter` command; but since you're using `article`, `\chapter` is undefined anyway.  Then in your comments you say you want an appendix-style of `\section`, which makes more sense in an `article`.

In any case, what you want, `titlesec` can provide (assuming that I correctly understand what you want):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\Appendiks}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{Appendiks}
\titleformat{\Appendiks}[display]{\Huge\filleft\scshape}{ \normalfont\bf\fontfamily{put}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{95pt}{0pt}\selectfont\thesection}{20pt}{}[\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\vspace{2ex}]
\titlespacing*{\Appendiks}{0cm}{0cm}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\section{The first Section}
\Appendiks{The first Appendix}
\section{The second Section}
\Appendiks{The second Appendix}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: \Appendiks command as requested]

I suggest that you want to change the styling (perhaps the numbering to alphabetical, the tradition for appendices) to make it clear to your readers that these are appendices, since it sounds like you want to intersperse them rather than put them all at the end, as the name implies.